# Flutter array in Text Widget

Tags: arrays, string, flutter, dart

I have an array that contains a list of String

```
var array = [
    "table",
    "laptop",
    "kitchen",
  ];
```

and I have a random number:

```
int i= Random().nextInt(2);
```

I want to show the random selected item in a text widget something like:

```
Text("your randomly selected item ist $array[i] ")
```

but that dosn't work.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `${array[i]}` instead of `$array[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use more than on variable value in string context, you should use `{}` like:

```
Text("your randomly selected item is ${array[i]}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like this:

```
var array = ["table","laptop","kitchen"];

int i= Random().nextInt(array.length);

Text("your randomly selected item ist ${array[i]} ");
```